# What's included in the base image?

Tags: freebsd

FreeBSD has some software included in the "base system", and optional software can be installed from pkg and the ports collection. What exactly is included in the base system? Is the list maintained somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD base system is a binary distribution, and best representation of its contents is a [source tree](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/). You can go up and under the base select releases and see contents of a particular release. There's an ongoing effort to make base system contents available as FreeBSD packages and this is somewhat working with FreeBSD 11, but with some reservations.